# mocking resttemplate exchange method returning null

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, junit, resttemplate

I am trying to write the Junit test case for exchange method but it its returning null, can anybody tell me what is mistake I am doing here

My Actual Code is

```
 HttpEntity httpEntity = cviBillingReportDateUtility.getHttpClient();

ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                personApiURI,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                httpEntity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PersonDTO>>() {
                }
        );
```

My Junit test code is like

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(any(String.class),
            eq(HttpMethod.GET),
            any(HttpEntity.class),
            eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PersonDTO>>(){})
    )).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>>(personList,HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: Perhaps `(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PersonDTO>>() {}).equals(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PersonDTO>>() {})` returns `false`

Comment: yes, even I tried with `any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class )` ..that's also not working

Comment: If you put any in all args, does it work?

Comment: I tried it wont work

Comment: Can you show more code? Perhaps the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

```
 PowerMockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<cCustomerGroup>>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);

#You have to also mock endpoint url like below,

    @Value("${url.customergroup}")
    private String getCustomerGroups;
  

@Before
public void initialize() {
 ReflectionTestUtils.setField(customerGroupService, "getCustomerGroups", 
 "http://localhost:8080/services/rest/customergroups");
 }
```